# Proof of parametrization

Tags: parametrization

Suppose that I have an implicit curve $$F(x, y)=0 $$
and a candidate $$ \overline{r} : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$$
for its parametrization.

$$ \overline{r}(t) =x(t)\hat{i}+y(t) \hat{j}, \ \ \ t\in I $$

How could I prove rigorously that the parametrization is correct, i.e. it attains all points of the curve and no extra points? I already know that $$ F(x(t), y(t))=0. $$

Comment: I suspect it will depend quite a bit on $F$ and $\overline r$. Do you have an example in mind?